# Rails: controller method reading wrong model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I've got two models (`Articles` and `Documents`) and I'm working with them from a third controller (called `Share`). I've written this method in that controller to track clicks on articles and the like:

```
def read_more(a)
  @article = Article.find(a)
  impressionist(@article)
end
```

And for some bizarre reason my app tries to find a `Document` with an ID of, say, 17, instead of an `Article`. I'm completely stumped.

Any ideas? Cheers!

**EDIT:**

The log readout is:

```
Started GET "/share/read_more/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-17 09:37:49 +1100
Processing by ShareController#show as JS
Parameters: {"ftp"=>"read_more", "id"=>"17"}
Document Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "17"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Document with id=17):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, should anyone else come into a similar issue.

```
def read_more
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  impressionist(@article)
  render :json => "Read."
end
```

Apparently you can't have arguments in controller methods.